# Problems with returning String[] from Java Web Service to Swing client

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, web

I am just trying to return a String[] from a @webMethod to the ws swing client. The problem is that it is not returning anything. When I test the web service it shows

```
Method returned

net.java.dev.jaxb.array.StringArray : "net.java.dev.jaxb.array.StringArray@2f741802"
SOAP Request

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:getEmployeeNames xmlns:ns2="http://employee.bank.com/"/>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
SOAP Response

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:getEmployeeNamesResponse xmlns:ns2="http://employee.bank.com/">
            <return>
                <item>73869</item>
            </return>
        </ns2:getEmployeeNamesResponse>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

the web service method is

```
    public String[] getEmployeeNames()
   {
     String[] nameList = ........;
     return nameList;
   }
```

Comment: post some code and request response

Comment: Sorry, I was editing it